# git stage in eclipse when all junit tests are passed

Tags: git, eclipse, junit

Is there a way in eclipse to git stage changes when all junit tests are green?

As one possible way to do it could be some macro functionality, I was looking for that, but only found this question: https://superuser.com/questions/185650/how-do-i-create-a-macro-short-cuts-in-eclipse